# Per-environment configuration accessible during CloudFormation/CDK in Amplify projects

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

Is there a way to have configuration per Amplify environment accessible to custom CloudFormation/CDK code?

For example, let's say I want to customise the "auth" component, so I end up with an override.ts in the backend/auth/ folder with some CDK code along the lines of:

```js
...

export function override(resources: AmplifyAuthCognitoStackTemplate) {
    resources.addCfnResource(
    {
      type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider",
      properties: {
        AttributeMapping: {
          email: "email",
          given_name: "given_name",
          family_name: "family_name",
          username: "sub"
        },
        ProviderDetails: {
          client_id: "...",
          client_secret: "...",
          authorize_scopes: "openid email profile",
        },
    ...
}
```

I'd like to customise the 'client_id' and 'client_secret' depending on my environment (I don't want an "if" statement in my override.ts as this would result in a per-environment switch appearing at each configuration point.)

One approach seems to be to try a DIY approach with the ["hooks" functionality](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/command-hooks/#executing-different-logic-based-on-environment), copying a configuration map into place - all the override.ts could then presumably import this and use it.

This doesn't solve the problem in the CloudFormation, although as long as it works in the CDK you can work around this.

What do people do to solve this problem?  The example I've given above is really just the tip of the iceberg, as you could easily imagine lots more per-environment configuration.